# how to change the javascript document in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change my js document in HTML.
the HTML code like this:

```
<div id="content_FoodSales_bar" class="p_chart>
    <script id="box1" type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/FoodSales_bar_mysql.js"></script>;
</div>
```

and I want to change the src attribute in script.
the javascript document to achieve that like this:

```
$('#box1').attr("src",'../scripts/FoodSales_bar2_mysql.js');
```

and this:

```
document.getElementById('box1').src='../scripts/FoodSales_bar2_mysql.js';
```

but both of them cannot work. how can I do?

Comment: what do you mean? the code is working. You run this code/script after the DOM is loaded right?

Comment: I solve this problem. Someone told me that src cannot be modified in <script>.